# How does neo4j perform MATCH?

Tags: neo4j, graph-databases

To search for a node that satisfies a pattern, does neo4j perform a DFS/BFS over the whole graph assuming no index structure is available?

For instance, given the following query:

```
MATCH (movie:Movie)
RETURN movie.title
```

In my opinion, if we do not store the list of movies, we need to go through all the nodes to answer this query.

Another example is the following query:

```
   MATCH (:Person {name: 'Oliver Stone'})--(movie:Movie) 
   RETURN movie.title
```

This would require finding all Person nodes with name 'Oliver Stone' and check each of them whether they connect to a Movie node. The first step would require going through all the Person nodes.

If you could link me to any documentation/code, that would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can prefix your queries with `PROFILE` or `EXPLAIN` to understand what's going on under the hood: https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/query-tuning/how-do-i-profile-a-query/#how-do-i-profile-a-query

Execution plans will show if/what indices are used e.g.

Comment: Thanks. From the query plans, I have just found all the query operations: https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/execution-plans/operators/. Some of them need to go through all the nodes.